# Are non-sticky services restarted when a task is restored?

Tags: android, android-service, android-task

If a task is destroyed in the background and the activity stack is later restored, are services originally started by that task also restored?  More specifically, **will they be restarted in this situation even if their `onStartCommand(...)` returned `START_NOT_STICKY`?**

I'm asking because setting `android:alwaysRetainTaskState` to false [does not guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290726/androidalwaysretaintaskstate-false-not-being-respected-task-state-always-ret) that task state will *not* be retained.  I'm concerned that if my task is killed and restored, the top activity may be one that depends on services conditionally started by the launcher activity.  I considered the solutions suggested on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423571/prevent-activity-stack-from-being-restored) and the other one.  But then it occurred to me that if the services will be automatically restarted, I don't need to worry about it.  (And the fact that services are running may help keep the app alive anyway, so this may be an extreme edge case if it's a concern at all.)

I want to avoid `START_STICKY` because it causes services to be restarted **without a task** a few seconds after they're killed.  (At least, this is what happens when the app is swiped from recents.)  They shouldn't be restarted until the task is restored.

Comment: this depends on what is returned http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY

Comment: @QAMAR I'm hoping to avoid using `START_STICKY` because it creates another problem.  If the app is swiped from recents, [the service is restarted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18618060/1953590) a few seconds later without any task associated with it.

Comment: see other constants like START_FLAG_RETRY START_REDELIVER_INTENT etc

Comment: @QAMAR `START_FLAG_RETRY` doesn't seem relevant, and `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` behaves in the same problematic way as `START_STICKY`.